# iOS : hide a notification preview after it appeared on lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to re-produce a behaviour used by the gmail app.
When an email is received, a preview notification is displayed on the lock screen but when I read that email on another device (email marked as read) the notification disapear from the lock screen.

Note : To test this you will need your laptop and an iPhone with the gmail app instaled.

1 - on your laptop send an email to yourself

2 - a notification preview will appear on your iPhone screen.

3 - Without touching the phone go again to your laptop and mark that email as read.

4 - the notification will disapear from your iPhone screen

Does any one know what code(Methods, API) is is used to create this.

Regards,

Comment: Marked as duplicate. It seems that the silent push notifications introduced in iOS7 allow this. If not then reply to me and I can open this again for you. Thanks